# Automated WSUS reporting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, automation, wsus, report

We have WSUS 3.0 SP2 installed and I was wondering if it is possible to schedule
and e-mail reports in pdf format or perhaps place them on a shared folder?

Answer (score 3):

What is your host OS?

Small Business Server has an option similar to this, built-in (not sure if it does PDF).  It gives a report for every segment of SBS.  Beyond that, the WSUS mmc has an entry for this under under options -> Email Notifications.

For PDF format... it'd be a bit harder.   I doubt you'd like the answer, but you may be able to create a powershell script with the required data and then print to a PDF creator utility via cmdline.  Links below that may be helpful:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/17/use-powershell-to-perform-basic-administrative-tasks-on-wsus.aspx

http://blog.uvm.edu/jgm/2011/07/22/wsus-reporting-with-powershell/

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?686537-Converting-Printing-files-to-PDF

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer 2.2 (MBSA) still does not support emailing of reports, but it is very command-line friendly.

If you're feeling scripty, you can use MBSA and PowerShell to generate your reports. Here is a sample script on the TechNet gallery that you could probably modify pretty easily to email the report to you.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ca419380-c6e4-444d-927d-dee9fa820129